# Что возвращает return?

Tags: java, функции

Никак не могу понять, что должен возвращать **return**, **true** или **false**, или же вообще какое-то значение?

Comment: return никому ничего не должен, пусть возвращает то, что вам нужно

Comment: @vp_arth так дело в том, что ide ругается, если не поставить return true/false/значение, например, в методе типа int. Только вот я не понимаю, когда там нужно ставить true/false/значение

Comment: Если вам ничего не нужно от метода, измените сигнатуру на void

Comment: Не обязательно, что - то должно быть нужно от метода, тут дело принципа, `return` - либо возвращает, либо останавливает, если дальше условия не нужно выполнять. Но не увидел, не одного примера с кодом.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Функция return в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816611/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-return-%d0%b2-java)

Answer (score 5):

Оператор `return` используется для выполнения явного возврата из метода. То есть он снова передает управление объекту, который вызвал данный метод. Если метод должен был вернуть значение, то после оператора `return` должно быть выражение.

Некоторые методы объявляются как `void`, так как они не возвращают никакого значения.

Маленький кусочек кода, чтобы было проще понять:

```
public class Main {
    public static void example1(int i) {
        System.out.println("Текст до return");
        if (i > 0){
            return; // так как метод void, то return ничего не возвращает
        }
        System.out.println("Текст после return");
    }
    public static int example2(int i){
        return i; // так, как метод типа int, то вернем число
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        example1(1);
        System.out.println(example2(0));
        }
    }
```